# How to customize ASP.Net textbox with some read only non editable characters?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, textbox

I am attaching an asp.net textbox image[image]

I want my textbox should have two brackets and one dash, for the numbers like (92)42-83823823, i want brackets and dash to be non-editable, and i dont want to use ajax control toolkit or some component other than asp.net text box control or jquery, is there some way to tackle such situation.

Comment: You should probably explain why you don't want to use jQuery or something like it -- otherwise people will keep giving you irrelevant answers.

Comment: @egrunin: I think the problem with his "no other libraries" premise is that he's going to have to write the whole thing himself.  And, if that's the case, then the question isn't a fit for Stack Overflow.  Nobody here is going to write it for him.  If, in the process of writing it himself, he has a specific question then that would be welcome here.  But right now the most answerable form of the current question is "how would I achieve this functionality" and the answer is "use this other component."

Comment: @egrunin: If the question is, indeed, "how do I achieve this functionality without using a component which provides this functionality" then the answer is "write it yourself, and good luck with that."

Comment: @David: his premise is probably based on faulty information. (For example, maybe he doesn't know that jQuery is pure javascript.) If he explains it, we can help him over that.

Comment: jQuery is the internal part of .Net now, i talked about some external components like telerik controls or ajax control toolkit.

Comment: @MuhammadAtifAgha: You'd be surprised how often developers are instructed (by management, clients, so-called "senior" developers, etc.) to develop an ASP.NET web application and "don't use JavaScript because we don't support it."  I always enjoy pointing out that basic ASP.NET functionality relies on JavaScript being emitted to the browser :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) does exactly what you want.  For a phone number, the code to mask the `input` element would look something like this:

```
$("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

where `phone` is the `id` of the `input` element.

Either way, client-side code is definitely the way to do this.  From the server-side code's perspective, it just wants the resulting value (and will re-validate it, of course).  The client-side code is what's creating the more dynamic user experience.

**Edit:** I suppose this violates your requirement to not use "some component other than asp.net text box control."  There's a good reason for that, though.  The ASP.NET `TextBox` by itself doesn't have this functionality.  You can write code to make it happen, and it will be JavaScript code.  Or, you can use code that's already been written and continue about the more meaningful parts of your application :)

Comment: JavaScript is the part of ASP.Net, and jQuery is officialy included in asp.net, so i will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why you don't want to use a UI toolkit. I think this can be acomplished by using the masked input jQuery plug-in http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/maskedinput

Answer (score 0):

Impractical at best. MaskedTextBox or similar is what you want. You'd have to write piles of event handlers to do this, and if you were already using, or needed to use the same ones, the results could be unfortunate...

A quick and nearly way would be when the TextBox gets focus strip out the formatting, when it loses focus put it back in. Not exactly what you want, but it's way simpler.

Think about scenarios like.
The user selects 2)42-8, and then presses 5.
You could force the ) in, where does the dash go though?
(95)-3823823 ???
And where's the cursor position within the box after this?

You are making a big club so people can beat you with it.